# Unable to extract package from Storefront

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, sxa-storefront

**What I am doing**: I am installing `Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.1` `on-premise` version. I already have `Sitecore 9.1.1` up and running.
The Sitecore documentation, in section `3.2. Add a missing block to the deployment script file`, says to update the `Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront 2.0.181.zip`. Accordingly, I unzipped the package and as per the documentation further tried to unzip the `package.zip`.

**What is the issue**: I am getting errors in unzipping the `package.zip`.

Logs while unzipping with 7-zip:

[image]

Log with `Extract All` command:
[image]

**What I have already checked**:

1. The zip file was unblocked under the safety tab.
2. The issue is not of the path length.
3. A fresh download also has this problem.
4. `Everyone` has full right on the folder concerned.

Please suggest how I should move forward.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a easier way to do this since you are using 7zip.

1. Extract just the XML file and edit it
2. Drag and drop it back to the 7zip interface.
3. Save the archive and you are done

[image: 7Zip Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that after installation
See here 
https://d0cnet.wordpress.com/2019/07/29/installing-sitecore-experience-commerce-9-1-default-storefront-bug-workaround/